# Como hacer para que en una tabla se guarde datos por medio de un solo botón?

Tags: php, html5

Así es como se muestra actualmente, con botones en cada fila:

[image: Así es como se muestra actualmente,con botones en cada fila]

Lo que quiero es que en un solo botón se de en guardar y se guarde cada check box de cada fila, sin necesidad de andar dando clic en el botón de guardar de cada fila. Mi duda es, ¿cómo lograr eso?

El código es el siguiente:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.Control</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Asistencia</th>


        <th class="disabled-sorting">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>

        <th>No.Control</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
         <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Asistencia</th>


    </tr>
</tfoot>

<?php
//Conexón a la base de datos

include 'conexion.php';
//Consulta para la informacion de los becarios por medio del id
$consulta = "SELECT u.USU_NOMBRE, u.USU_APELLIDO_PATERNO, u.ID_USUARIO,
b.BEC_ID_USUARIO, b.ID_BECARIO FROM usuarios u, becario b
WHERE

b.BEC_ID_USUARIO = u.ID_USUARIO";

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);

$i = 0;
$fecha_actual=date("d/m/Y");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)){

$var_nombre     =     $row['USU_NOMBRE'];
$var_apellidop  =     $row['USU_APELLIDO_PATERNO'];

$var_idbec       =     $row['ID_BECARIO'];

$var_id         =     $row['ID_USUARIO'];

$i++;

?>
<!--Envia los datos por el metodo POST para cada input -->
<form method="post" action="registrar_asistencia.php">


<tbody >
    <tr>

        <td><input class ="col-md-5"type="number"  name = "idbec" value="<?php echo $var_idbec; ?>" readonly="readonly"/></td>
        <td><?php echo $var_nombre ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $var_apellidop; ?></td>
        <!--Obtiene la fecha actual por medio de php-->
        <td><input type="date" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" readonly="readonly" /></td>   <!--<?php echo$fecha_actual ?>-->

       <!-- <td contenteditable="true"> </td>-->
        <td> <input type="hidden" id="checkbox"  name="asistencia" value="0" /> <center>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"  name="asistencia" value="1" /></center></td>



        <td>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd">Agregar</button>




        </td>
     <!--   no=".$fila['CAL_NIVEL_INGLES']."-->

    </tr>
</form>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener un form que incluya todas las filas de la tabla, en lugar de un form por fila, quitar los botones de cada fila y dejar solo uno al final que envíe todos los datos en una sola llamada. Yo lo he puesto en una fila pero se puede sacar para que esté fuera de la tabla

Eso sí, tienes que poner distintos identificadores y nombres a cada uno de los checkbox para poder identificarlos cuando te llegan al servidor:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>No.Control</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Asistencia</th>
        <th class="disabled-sorting">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>No.Control</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Asistencia</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>

<!--Envia los datos por el metodo POST para todos los inputs -->
<form method="post" action="registrar_asistencia.php">
<tbody>
<?php
    //Conexón a la base de datos
    include 'conexion.php';
    //Consulta para la informacion de los becarios por medio del id
    $consulta = "SELECT u.USU_NOMBRE, u.USU_APELLIDO_PATERNO, u.ID_USUARIO, b.BEC_ID_USUARIO, b.ID_BECARIO FROM usuarios u, becario b WHERE
    b.BEC_ID_USUARIO = u.ID_USUARIO";
    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);

    $i = 0;
    $fecha_actual = date("d/m/Y");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {
        $var_nombre = $row['USU_NOMBRE'];
        $var_apellidop = $row['USU_APELLIDO_PATERNO'];
        $var_idbec = $row['ID_BECARIO'];
        $var_id = $row['ID_USUARIO'];
        $i++;
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class ="col-md-5" type="number" name="idbec_<?= $var_idbec; ?>" value="<?= $var_idbec; ?>" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td><?= $var_nombre; ?></td>
        <td><?= $var_apellidop; ?></td>
        <td>
            <!--Obtiene la fecha actual por medio de php-->
            <input type="date" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <center>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_<?= $var_idbec; ?>" name="asistencia_<?= $var_idbec; ?>" value="1" />
            </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-danger btn-wd">Agregar todos</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta amigo, intentare hacerlo de esa manera :)!!